# Do not fail assert_frame_equal if values difference is less than 10%

Tags: python, pandas, unit-testing

I am making unittests for my script. The idea of the script is to add columns to existing DataFrame. The problem is that because of the way I am getting those new values, they sometimes differ. The difference is not significant and its usually 10 out of 100 and difference less than 0.01 (both values are float).

This is the line I am using. I am aware of **check_less_precise**, however it is not working in my case.

```
assert_frame_equal(df, test_df, check_dtype=False, check_like=True, check_less_precise=True)
```

error is:

```
DataFrame.iloc[:, 0] values are different (10.98214 %)
```

What I would like is to be able to say if the less than 10% of the values are different, pass the test, else fail it.

I checked the docs for assert_frame_equal and I am not sure this is possible by design. Additional code might be needed, however I am blocked, any ideas how this might be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`check_less_precise` - option may be bool or int. In case it is int the number says how many digits to compare. Also to make it work, you need to set `check_exact` option to False.

```
assert_frame_equal(df, test_df, check_dtype=False, check_like=True, check_exact=False, check_less_precise=3)
```

Comment: Thank you. By default "False" is equal to 3 digits after decimal points, however, when I changed it to 2 it is all good. This will work for me. Still I was hoping to actually catch the percentage of different values and make the decision based on that.

Comment: You can check abs((df - test_df) / test_df) - than you may check avg error, std div e t.c. :-)

Comment: Hmm interesting, when I check the abs for the column abs((df['col'] - test_df['col']) / test_df['col']) it says: 0. Then I get the msg: DataFrame.iloc[:, 157] values are different (0.01786 %). I am starting to think that when I save the dataframe as csv and read it again, it somehow changes the dtype of some columns.